# Not remove localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Why is this happening? i need remove 2 keys, but remove only 1 key

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('2', 'lalala')
localStorage.setItem('3', 'lalala')

for (var i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length; i++){
if (localStorage.key(i) > 1)
{
alert (localStorage.key(i)) //show 2 time
localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i)) //remove 1 time (remove 1 key)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use numerical keys https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4eLv7vgq/